# Metadata Does Not seem to update correctly

Tags: metadata, react-apollo, hasura

Our company uses Hasura Cloud with a React js front end with gQlApollo.
I recently added a new column "myString" to type "myType" in our database and was able to successfully update our Hasura Cloud instance by resetting the Metadata within settings.

I know this worked because when I use the API on Hasura Cloud I am able to successfully return the new column and its value.

I also see that the graphQl Engine metadata is green as shown here [status of graphQl engine metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQMuM.png)

The problem is when I try to query this new column locally it seems that this metadata is not successfully being updated there. I have no local hasura core so the suggestion online to preform a `hasura metadata clear` does not apply to me.

I have tried:

- resetting my browser history
- run `hasura init` and reset the meta data after which did not fix my problem

Any idea how I can accomplish resetting the metadata locally?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue! It was because I had not changed the permissions for the newly created column in cloud.hasura.io. Now that I have added that it works without needing to reset the Metadata at all.